# Why was my edit to remove a rude comment rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I recently attempted to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19252351) an answer because I felt it didn't fit the ["Be nice" model](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Adding "That's ... ehm... simple math." was unnecessary, rude and belittling. So I attempted to remove the remark and leave the actual answer there.

But my edit was rejected because "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability."

I've edited posts for containing profanity in the past and those were accepted, both profanity and mean language [are not allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22232/are-expletives-cursing-swear-words-or-vulgar-language-allowed-on-se-sites). So why was this edit rejected?

Comment: Note that for this particular case instead you probably should have just voted/flagged to close - there is even suggested duplicate in comments... I don't think having multiple "Why integer division produce wrong results"  per language is useful...

Comment: Unnecessary? Yes. Rude? I'm not sure. The answerer think that is simple, so... why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I tend to agree that the text you attempted to edit was unnecessarily belittling. However, your edit was no less disparaging. When attempting to correct a mistake, it is helpful to avoid making a similar mistake in the process!

Remember, editing is a form of communication, a conversation between an author and someone looking to improve on their work. If you've ever had your own writing handed back to you with a red line drawn through it and no explanation, you know precisely how belittling that feels... Well, this is how your edit would've appeared to the reviewers (including the author of the post itself):

[image: Comment: removed rude comment]

[As Makoto notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365247/why-was-my-edit-to-remove-a-rude-comment-rejected/365249#365249), the edit appears to strip out the only explanatory text in the post. On top of that, your explanation for *why* you were doing this is a terse "Removed rude comment". This was your big chance to talk to the author of that comment, convince them that there's a better way to explain the logic they've posted... But you didn't. In effect, you asserted that their words were rude and that it would be better if they had made no attempt to explain their answer at all.

Here's my attempt:

[image: Several people saw the previous explanation here as somewhat belittling, and also not particularly explanatory; attempt to address both. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365247/why-was-my-edit-to-remove-a-rude-comment-rejected]

Now, I can't guarantee this will go over any better; editing - like any sort of commentary - tends to hit a lot of tender spots. But, I at least made an effort to be sensitive toward both the author and their readers; at the end of the day, this is as much as most of us can do.

Comment: I deleted the answer. Thanks for your effort though. I guess the PC police wins again.

Comment: Well, I tried @Mena. Please remember, the goal for Stack Overflow is a collaborative work - in many senses of that term. Our efforts here go on to be seen and used by a much greater audience than that for which we initially write, and to be effective that often requires revisions to the language we use; I've personally benefited from the efforts of many, many editors in my time here, and hope to pay it forward whenever I get the chance.

Comment: @Shog9 Thank you for attempting to make the answer more appropriate for the site. I thought it solved the problem perfectly. I'm also glad the answer was deleted though as there was a much better one that had already been accepted anyway. I will follow your advice when suggesting edits in the future.

Comment: @Shog I have too. I embrace collaboration, and many of my answers have been edited by others for the greater good. This doesn't mean I'm happy caving in to fanatics. Luckily as I mentioned in a comment (since then deleted), there is a much better answer than mine to that question, so deleting my answer doesn't have any relevant impact on the Q&A quality (nor editing it for that matter).

Answer (score 10):

The answer doesn't read any *better* when you're done with it.  It's basically a one-liner of code, which many people would feel demands/begs an explanation for.

Fundamentally I don't disagree with what you're saying - I don't think that it's *mean* per se, since calling something "simple" isn't inherently rude - but it *probably* shouldn't be there.  Issue is, if it's removed, it doesn't *improve* the answer, nor does it really make it any more readable.  Worse, it then reads identically to *another* answer which just has the one-liner.

So in this case I'd recommend that you leave it be and let someone who doesn't have their edits go to the review queues handle it.  This is a ticky-tack sort of edit that reviewers aren't going to really spend a lot of time looking over or eyeing over to be sure that the nuances are correct here.

Comment: It was the tone I found rude more than the word simple. But from what I'm hearing you say, it would have been better to edit the comment rather than just remove it? And then let it go if it's rejected?

Comment: I don't think having edit privileges would help here. The person who rejected the edit owns the answer, so they would probably just roll the change back.

Comment: @Laurel:  Then you deal with it like you do *any* rollback war.  I don't see the problem there.